# No provider for MatDialog when using standalone components and services

Tags: angular

I have a library project I am trying to build with a sandbox project; it is referenced for testing purposes.  My issue is that my confirmation service isn't allowing me to use my modal module.

I have a list of tasks, and this list of tasks appears. When I click on the task, it shows up to the right of the list. However, when I try to add my confirmation service to my details.component.ts file, it errors out and says:

```
Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(Standalone[TasksDetailsComponent])[ConfirmationService -> ConfirmationService -> ConfirmationService -> ConfirmationService -> MatDialog -> MatDialog]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for MatDialog!
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(Standalone[TasksDetailsComponent])[ConfirmationService -> ConfirmationService -> ConfirmationService -> ConfirmationService -> MatDialog -> MatDialog]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for MatDialog!
```

However, my list component is a standalone component, just like the details component.

The details component constructor has this:

```
private _confirmationService: ConfirmationService,
```

while the confirmation service file has this:

```
private _matDialog: MatDialog = inject(MatDialog);
constructor(matDialog: MatDialog) {
        this._matDialog = matDialog;
    }
```

the decorator for the details.component.ts looks like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'tasks-details',
    templateUrl: './details.component.html',
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    standalone: true,
    imports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, MatDialogModule, MatButtonModule, NgIf, MatIconModule, MatMenuModule, RouterLink, MatDividerModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule, TextFieldModule, NgFor, MatRippleModule, MatCheckboxModule, NgClass, MatDatepickerModule, FindByKeyPipe, DatePipe],
})
```

i don't see anything logically wrong with this. i am at a loss. I have tried using resources like Chat GPT but it doesn't understand standalone component decorators yet.

i should mention, once the details.component tries to load, i get that first error listed above, but if I try to click it again. it gives the following error:

```
core.mjs:10920  ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG0200: Circular dependency in DI detected for ConfirmationService. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0200
Error: NG0200: Circular dependency in DI detected for ConfirmationService
```

what could make this a Circular Dependency?

Comment: I don't know if it's related to your problem, but change the `imports` array to: `imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, MatDialogModule, MatButtonModule, MatIconModule, MatMenuModule, MatDividerModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule, TextFieldModule, MatRippleModule, MatCheckboxModule, MatDatepickerModule, FindByKeyPipe]`.

Comment: You can save a few lines of code by changing the confirmation service like this: `constructor(private _matDialog: MatDialog) {}`

Comment: Also if you can share a [minimal and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), that'd help us see it in more depth.

Comment: did you raise issue on angular material size?